# User cp1252 as Javascript charset in IE

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I am having a HTML site declared and encoded as UTF-8. My Javascript sources are encoded with cp1252.

So i use this to set the encoding

```
<script src="my_cp1252_encoded_file.js" charset="cp1252" ></script>
```

This works in Mozilla but not in IE. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CP1252 is likely to be an alias provided by Gecko/Firefox that maps to Windows-1252.  Internet Explorer [supports<sup>1</sup> Windows-1252](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752010(VS.85).aspx) as a value and so does [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Character_Sets_Supported_by_Gecko).  Therefore,

```
<script src="my_cp1252_encoded_file.js" charset="Windows-1252"></script>
```

should work.

<sup>1</sup>This list appears to not have been updated since Internet Explorer 5.  I couldn't find a newer list.